# Android: reuse datepicker

Tags: java, android, android-activity, datepicker

I need help with a `DatePicker`.I followed the tutorial developer/android.com and I created my datepicker. The problem is that I need to use the datepicker in almost all my actiity..
So, how do I reuse my `MyDatePicker` class in other activity without having to write all the code each time ?

edit2:

```
public class MyDatePicker extends DatePicker {

                    private EditText mDateDisplay; 
                    private Button mPickDate;
                    private int mYear;
                    private int mMonth;
                    private int mDay;

                    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;

                    public MyDatePicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
                        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
                                           ///all methods
```

I do not need only the simple widget in layout, I would need a widget that opens by pressing a button.. this changes my EditText field.
putting the "address class " in the layout compiler said me: The following classes could not be instantiated: MyDatePicker.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this

```
class MyDataPicker extends DatePickerDialog{
    int year,  monthOfYear, dayOfMonth;
    final Calendar c;
    Date d1;
    public MyDataPicker(Context context, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener callBack, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth){ 
        super(context,  callBack, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
        this.year=year;  this.monthOfYear=monthOfYear; this.dayOfMonth=dayOfMonth;
         d1= new Date(year,  monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
        c = Calendar.getInstance();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker datepicker, int year, int month, int day){
            long timeinmilies = d1.getTime();
            Date d = new Date(year, month,day);
            long millis = d.getTime();
            if(millis<=timeinmilies){
                this.year = year; this.monthOfYear = month; this.dayOfMonth = day;
            }
            datepicker.updateDate(this.year,  monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
            super.onDateChanged(datepicker,this.year,  monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
    }
}






private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener myDateSetListener
  = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener(){
   @Override
   public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // set Date in EditText or textView Here

    DOB.setText((monthOfYear+1)+"-"+dayOfMonth+"-"+year);
   }


 };



// button click to open datepicker

public void onClickPickDate(View view){
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int myYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int myMonth = (c.get(Calendar.MONTH));
    int  myDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

  MyDataPicker datePickerDialog =  new MyDataPicker(this,myDateSetListener,myYear, myMonth, myDay);

  datePickerDialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create a clss by extending datepicker to have your functionality and simply use it through xml layouts like any other component.You can use something lke

```
 <com.yourpackagename.yourdatepickerclass....
```

Comment: y, I do not need only the simple widget in layout, I would need a widget that opens by pressing a button.. this changes my EditText field.
I need to reuse this function in many activity...like this:http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-datepicker.html i need use this in all my activity

Comment: no errors in the code, it gives me errors when I try to open the activity..excuse me. I badly explained

Answer (score 0):

Since you have made a custom datepicker, you can reuse it in any of the layouts as a normal view by just specifying it as part of the layout . For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/jembalang.comfest.game"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <com.game.MyDatePicker
    android:id="@+id/game_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  </com.game.MyDatePicker>
  <Button 
    android:text="Button" 
    android:id="@+id/button1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

You need to use it by specifiting **packagename.customviewname** . Here in the above example, com.game is the package where MyDatePicker is kept.

Comment: how are you instantiating. post some code. Also , please don't use the name DatePicker for your Activity. Generally small things like this cause problems

Comment: Now I am confused, you have made an Activity called DatePicker . Then you are trying to extend it in MyDatePicker. I am talking about the DatePicker widget in android.

Comment: excuse me. I badly explained..
I do not need only the simple widget in layout, I would need a widget that opens by pressing a button.. this changes my EditText field.
putting the "address class " in the layout compiler said me: The following classes could not be instantiated: MyDatePicker. edit2.     thanks for the help, and sorry me for the bad explanation .. im a newbie qq

Comment: for example http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-datepicker.html i need use this in all my activity, without rewriting all the code in each activity

Answer (score 0):

first i am goint to explaint on english is not my native languaje but i hope what you undertand what i am writing for you

I think what i can help with your problem

first create one class wich is goint to be your dialog your screen

```
class DatePickerFragment(
private val contextP: Context,
private val listener: DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener) : DialogFragment() {

override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    val c = Calendar.getInstance()
    val year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)
    val month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
    val day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    val picker = DatePickerDialog(contextP, listener, year, month, day)
    val today = c.timeInMillis
    picker.datePicker.minDate = today
    return picker
}

companion object {
    fun newInstance(
        listener: DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener,
        contextP: Context
    ): DatePickerFragment {
        return DatePickerFragment(contextP, listener)
    }
}
 }
```

then create this function to reuse y one file  or can be in one companion object

```
fun showDatePickerDialog(listener: DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener, fragment: Fragment) {
val newFragment =
    DatePickerFragment.newInstance(listener, fragment.requireContext())
fragment.activity?.let { newFragment.show(it.supportFragmentManager, "datePicker") }
}
```

then in your fragment implement for this listener

```
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener
```

then override the method

```
override fun onDateSet(datePicker: DatePicker?, year: Int, month: Int, day:Int) {
    //code what fire when the date is is set
}
```

then in your activity or fragment call this funtion for example in one listener

```
 binding.selectDate.setOnClickListener {
        showDatePickerDialog(this,this)
    }
```

the first this do reference to your listener(DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener) in your fragment and the second this is your fragment and is all
with this code you can reuse the dialog Where you want